# Best/recommended way to convert Java 8 OffsetDateTime to localized string on android

Tags: java, android, datetime, java-8, date-formatting

I'm converting my Android app to use the new Java 8 date time classes using the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) instead of the legacy Java `Date` class.

What would be the best/recommended way to format the date and time to present to the user based on the user's Android preferences? While using the `Date` class, I used the `DateFormat` as such:

```
DateFormat.getDateFormat(context).format(new Date()) // for date
DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context).format(new Date()) // for time
```

These methods receive a `Date` as the parameter. Should I continue to use them by converting my `OffsetDateTime` to `Date` or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Hopefully you know about [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) adapting *ThreeTen-Backport* for Android.

Comment: Yes, that's the one I'm using, but thank you for point it out for future references.

Answer (score 4):

## `org.threeten.bp.format`

Forget about `DateFormat` & `Date`. Those terrible classes were replaced entirely years ago with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

See the [`org.threeten.bp.format`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/package-summary.html) package.

### `DateTimeFormatter`

Specifically, look at the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class and its `ofLocalized…` methods.

For more info, search for the equivalent classes from *java.time*. Formatting has been covered many many times already. The API and functionality will be nearly identical, so the existing posts will apply.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;

Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( l ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

> 11 mai 2019

### Using defaults

If you want to use the JVM’s current default values [for the time zone](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/ZoneId.html#systemDefault()) or [for the locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault-java.util.Locale.Category-), I suggest you do so explicitly. This way anyone reading your code knows you considered the zone/locale issues and consciously chose to use the default.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;

Locale l = Locale.getDefault() ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( l ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

Comment: The problem is not how to format, but how to format for the user Android system specification. The `DateFormat` I used is from Android that takes the application context and returns a `DateFormat` ready to use. I don't need to take care of localization myself.

Comment: @Erik Forget about `DateFormat`. I added a section on how to ask for the system default values for zone and for locale. Combine that with the `ofLocalized…` methods to fully localize according to the user’s current defaults. Note that if the formatting is critical, you should confirm the zone and locale with the user. Any code in any app in any thread can change either default at any moment during runtime and immediately change the results of your code.